# pattern match special charecters and display contents between the pattern

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

My apache log format is as below

```
192.168.10.1 <"www.mytest.com"> <-"-"-> <--“192.168.10.90"--> [2020-07-10 03:35:46 PDT] >1008< 2470 3006 "https" <---"GET /content/landingpage.css HTTP/1.1"---> >>200<< 2447 <<"https://www.mytest.com/en/video-landing.html?sessionid=156833130903879801B5H7">> <<-"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"->> "-" <<--"-"-->> "-" <<---"-"--->> <<<"-">>>
```

I need to run the command to get the value between >>xxx<< which is httpd status code.

I used below combinations without any luck.

`cat access_log | awk -F '[>>]' '{print $2}'`

`cat access_log | awk -F '">"|^>|>$' '{print $2}'`

`awk '/\>\>/,/\<\</' access_log`

`awk '/\^>\>/,/\<\<$/' access_log`

Best Regards,
KJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F '>>|<<' '{print $2}' access.log
```

This sets the field separator to be *either* `>>` or `<<`.  This means for `>>xxx<<` that the `>>` before `xxx` is treated as a field separator *and* the `<<` after the `xxx` is *also* treated as a field separator.

On your sample input, this produces `200`:

```
$ awk -F '>>|<<' '{print $2}' access.log 
200
```

Comment: Thanks this worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If the wanted quantity is between the first set of `>>` and `<<` and consists of digits (such as a port no.), you can use `sed` with a basic REGEX as:

```
sed 's/^.*>>\([0-9]*\)<<.*$/\1/1' access.log
```

Or with an extended REGEX if your `sed` supports it, e.g.

```
sed -E 's/^.*>>([0-9]+)<<.*$/\1/1' access.log
```

The ERE mandates one-or-more digit occur between `>>` and `<<`, but with the BRE it will match zero-or-more digits.

In both cases, the `/1` at the end of the normal substitution form specifies it should match the first occurrence of the pattern.

With your input in `access.log`, both return:

```
200
```

Comment: This works too.  Very good.